# PHP - Dynamically reference object property

Tags: php, object

I have code like :

```
$result = $object->property[0];
```

but I want to do something like :

```
if ($a) {  
  $property = 'blue' }  
else {  
  $property = 'black'}  
$result = $object->$property[0];
```

However this give me a `Cannot use string offset as an array` error.

Any pointers (no pun intended) appreciated.

Comment: Remove the leading `$` on the `$property[0];`

Answer (score 6):

Use braces:

```
$result = $object->{$property}[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

> $result = $object->{$property}